# How do i make a script to unrar archives in multiple folders

Tags: windows, script, winrar

Im not sure that this is supposed to be here but i didnt know where else to put it.
I got around 90 rar archives all in different folders how can i extract them at once?

Comment: What's the structure of these folders?  Do you want to extract them in place or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

A good overview of some more tools, mostly for Windows though:
http://obinshah.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/5-free-tools-to-extract-multiple-rarzip-archives/
http://youressential.blogspot.com/2009/04/reihen-auszug-mehrfache-rar-archive.html

I tried RAR Zombie.. but extracting multiple folders did not work for me (just filling the Log with endless lines, starting with growing number of '\').. Just mailed the author about it, and waiting for a reply!

Answer (score 0):

[RARZombie](http://www.robertnoack.com/rarzombie/) seems to be able to do what you want.

> RARZombie is an automatic mass unrar /
>   auto unrar program. It can unrar a
>   (virtually) unlimited number of
>   archives automatically in sequence
>   from folders of your choosing. It can
>   monitor folders of your choosing for
>   new archives and extract them as they
>   become available.